# URP Error using HPLaserJet M101-M106-IPP printer on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, hp, 22.04

After installing Ubuntu 22.04, instead of the print test or any other print job, I get this on the paper:

```
URP Error
     Subsystem: PARSER
     Error: NotImplemented
     File Name: urp_urf_processor.c
     Line Number: 753
```

My printer model is a HPLaserJet M101-M106-IPP (wireless connection).
Before installation of Ubuntu 22.04, it was fine both with Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 21.10.
It still works fine with Windows 11, so I am only having the problem on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I had found the decision at last. At a control page of CUPS (localhost:631), after changing PPD to "LaserJet M101-M106 - IPP Everywhere (grayscale)" driver I've got printer working.

Comment: You may post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes it seems the issue is persistent after 22.04 update. It has reverberated downstream to other distros built on Ubuntu 22.04. The case applies to our HP-Lasterjet-mfp-129. We are connected through Wifi. the Error Code is VERBATIM to @Andrey.

Comment: I have same issue on Fedora 36. It worked as expected on Fedora 35.

Comment: I have used the Monochrome instead of the RGB in the Printer Options, which made it printing again...

Answer (score 3):

Just select `Monochrome` in `Print Color Mode` instead of leaving it blank:

[image]

Or via file `~/.config/evince/print-settings` containing only the following two lines:

```
[Print Settings]
cups-ColorModel=Gray
```

The remaining lines of the file will be created during the first print job using `Evince Document Viewer`.

Comment: This works for printing PDFs but not libreoffice documents

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 23.04 Daily and my printer printed the same error.

### URP Error
Subsystem: PARSER
Error: NotImplemented
File Name: urp_urf_processor.c
Line Number: 753

I have Ubuntu 23.04 pre-relase.
Printer: HP_LaserJet_MFP_M130nw_B90D11.

I solved this issue (temporarily) by setting the "Print Color Mode" to Monochrome in Settings -> Printer -> Printer Options.

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

For a complete solution I had to go to Settings > Printers > Additional printer settings > [Select printer] > Printer Options > Printer color mode > Monochrome.

This allowed me to print everything correctly including test pages, PDFs and libreoffice documents.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** : install driver by running **hp-setup** in the terminal.

I am using ubunu 22.4 & the "HP-LaserJet-MFP-M426dw" hp printer, in my case , when I opened the settings > printers , the word **Driverless** was written beside my printer name , so I installed the driver for my hp printer by : 
1 - open the terminal 
2 - run : **hp-setup**

and I followed the prompt in the popup that appeared and installed the driver for my printer, which fixed the problem.